# API for obtaining image about specific title

Tags: php, web-services, api

I have an encyclopedia-like website and there are millions of pages.
Each page addresses a specific topic or issue.
Now my question is, is there a web service, API or any other service with which I can obtain an image relating to a word or title? For example I expect the service to return the picture of a car, if I passed it the string "car".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.flickr.com/services/api/

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview

But take copyright issues into account.